# Can't lock Apple Music app to Recent Apps on Samsung devices running Android 12

Tags: samsung, recents-screen, apple-music

I'm using Apple Music app on Samsung Galaxy S10e, Android 12. I used to be able to lock it in Recents so it wouldn't close with Close All. Now when I tap "Lock this app," nothing happens.

No other apps were affected. Uninstalling/reinstalling the app doesn't work. Rolling back to previous app versions doesn't work. Apple has no idea what I'm talking about when I try to get support.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. While I don't know why it happened, I think it's fair that Apple didn't have any idea since the locking app on the recent apps screen is not a universal feature in Android. It might be a quirk on Samsung's side instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's a fair point. I stand by my raccoon comment though!